# Getting a cookie from a website using lua [ Not a specific cookie / raw code ]

Tags: cookies, lua

I was wondering if there was a way to possibly get a cookie without using require() to get it, basically without using already existing tools (raw code). If anybody could help with this then i would inform me of a possible way to get cookies since i'm kind of bad at HTTP requests as a whole let alone getting certain info.

Comment: What library are you intending to use to make a http-request?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think the whole point of the question is to use no libraries whatsoever (?) which, of course, isn't possible in vanilla Lua.

Comment: In vanilla Lua you can `io.popen()` the external process `wget/curl` to send request and receive response with cookies.  If you are using Lua inside some game engine (or another API), there usually exist special functions to access the internet.